# How to create a dictionary and insert key with a list of value in R?

Tags: r, dictionary

I want to loop through content of a file, compute the key of each word and then store the words with same key in a list.

In python, it's like below:

```
dictionary = {}
for word in file:
    key = dosomecalucation(word)
    dictionary.setdefault(key, [])
    dictionary[key].append(word)
```

In R, how can I declare a dictionary with key as string and value as a list?
How can I check whether a key exist in the dictionary?

Comment: The equivalent of a python dictionary in R is more or less a named list, though [there are packages](https://github.com/mkuhn/dict) which offer a full dictionary class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`hash`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/) package for this task:

```
library(hash)

h <- hash()

for (word in file) {
    key <- dosomecalculation(word)
    if (!has.key(key, h)) {
        h[key] <- list()
    } else {
        h[key] <- append(h[[key]], word)
    }
}
```

Using `[[` for indexing (e.g. `h[["foo"]]`) will then return the corresponding list.

Comment: you directly assign h["foo"] <- list(), but I need to check whether "foo" exist in h, otherwise in a loop every time h["foo"] will be new list.